# CiviEvents with Shopping Cart - two email fields showing

Tags: civievent, drupal, profile

We discovered that when using CiviEvents with the shopping cart option, that the cart has the email field hardcoded. This is an issue when you have email in your online registration profile.

The biggest issue is when you want too send an event confirmation and are editing an event, you must use a profile that has email.

Anyone working on this?

Dets: Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.9

Sheila

Comment: Also experiencing this issue.

Comment: relates to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/civicrm-event-shopping-cart-auto-fill

Comment: any update on this -  I know it's been a while but D7 on CiviCRM 5.51 still has this issue