# CiviCRM Event Shopping Cart Auto Fill

Tags: civievent

When using Drupal 7.x and CiviCRM 4.6 we notice that the Checkout page does not autofill profile information for a logged in CiviCRM user. They must manually enter in their details, then face this bug: [CiviEvents with Shopping Cart - two email fields showing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14810/civievents-with-shopping-cart-two-email-fields-showing), and finally update their credit card payment information.

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will happens only for the admin user

Please try creating an user without admin right and try the same - should pre-populate the details on the screen.

I guess this helps !!!!

Comment: I confirm that when filling in as a user without admin roles my details pre-populated. It doesn't seem to be correct behaviour to me that they don't pre-populate for admin users.

Comment: Do you know which permission it is exactly that results in the details not being pre-populated?

Comment: It looks for is_administrator - !CRM_Event_Cart_Form_Cart::is_administrator() - I guess this helps!!!